# Switch view template based on model state in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I have a notification box in my Ember.js app that will change the text, styling, and buttons based on the value of a Status model. **How do I switch just the view (or template) for the notification box?** I don't want to transitionTo because the rest of the page shouldn't update, just that notification box.

I have a [JSFiddle with a complete example](http://jsfiddle.net/baalexander/FYWTK/3/). But here's the relevant parts to glance at:

The main template will render the notification bar ("statusState") and the regular view data.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="status">
  {{render "statusState" content}}
  <p>
  Other information not related to the status state, but still related to status goes here.
  </p>
  {{outlet}}
</script>
```

There's a separate template for each Status state ("pending", "ready", "finished"):

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="status/pending">
  <div style="background-color: grey">
    The status is pending.
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="status/ready">
  <div style="background-color: blue">
  The status is ready.
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="status/finished">
  <div style="background-color: green">
    The status is finished.
  </div>
</script>
```

The Status object is nothing special, and belongs to the StatusController:

```
App.StatusRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Status.create();
  }
});

App.Status = Ember.Object.extend({
  value: 0
});
```

My first attempt was to change the templateName of the view whenever the Status' value changes. But this feels hacky and doesn't even seem to respond to Status value changes:

```
App.StatusStateView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: function() {
    var templateName = 'status/pending';
    var value = this.get('controller.model.value');
    if (value === 1) {
      templateName = 'status/ready';
    }
    else if (value === 2) {
      templateName = 'status/finished';
    }
    return templateName;
  }.property('controller.model.value')
});
```

**In short, how would I change the view or template for just part of the page based on a model value that has more than 2 choices?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ember view template as a computed property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979729/ember-view-template-as-a-computed-property)

Comment: The trick is in the call to `rerender` in the linked example. Did that help?

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe - Thanks for the link. I'll go with your solution using templateNameBinding and rerender.

Comment: @WiredPrairie - templateName wasn't even getting fired on the model change, so I couldn't call re-render. I'll try it out with using a computedProperty elsewhere and templateNameBinding. Thanks!

Comment: FYI, I updated the JSFiddle with a working example using templateNameBinding here: http://jsfiddle.net/baalexander/FYWTK/4/

Comment: @baalexander You can make templateName the CP itself: http://jsfiddle.net/AUP57/1/

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would approach this. Add boolean computed properties to the model or controller and use a single template with the {{#if }} helper. e.g.

```
App.Status = Ember.Object.extend({
  value: 0,
  ready: function(){
     return this.get('value') === 1;
  }.property('value'),
  finished: function(){
     return this.get('value') === 2;
  }.property('value'),
  pending: function(){
     var value = this.get('value');
     return value !== 1 && value !== 2;
  }.property('value')
});
```

And in a single template:

```
{{#if pending}}
  I'm pending
{{/if}}
{{#if ready}}
  I'm ready!
{{/if}}
{{#if finished}}
  I'm finished.
{{/if}}
```

Comment: I like the turning of each state into a boolean, but the main reason I would like to avoid the single template route is there'll be a decent amount of HTML per status and I don't want to clutter up the template. Though I could call a partial...