# What is a recommended way to switch the application template in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've been playing around with Ember.js, and something that I couldn't easily find was how to switch out the base application template. For example, let's say that my application has 2 core layouts, one that is more presentational when the user is learning about the application before registering, and another that is the logged-in layout, the web application itself.

What is the recommended way to change which layout template is going to be used on a conditional basis?

**UPDATE**

From the solution, here is what I am doing: https://gist.github.com/eliperelman/8310055

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `layoutNameBinding` in the `ApplicationView`. This answer should get you started: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13980055/1234490 (start reading at  '**EDIT**').

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    if(... authenticated ...) {
      this.render('authenticated');
    else{
      this.render('guest');
    }
  }
});
```

This would change the entire application template, but keep the same application controller for both templates (you can pass a hash into the render method with a controller to use).